# How could I acomplish a TUI similar to the one of terminal fzf?

Tags: terminal, interface, ncurses, ansi-escape, terminfo

I'm developing a 6502 emulator in C and I want make a interface similar to the one of fzf, something like this:

[image]

notice that the interface doesn't clear the entire screen. I want to make something brief like that but to dump the most important registers of the CPU, etc.

I've already tried with ncurses but it always clears the screen.

Comment: fzf is open source, you can study its code. For SO, your question here is much too broad: It basically asks about a full how-to. This makes it not really suitable here. Also, nobody needs images of your desktop background, though I admit that an image is called for here. Maybe you could improve the question if you started with the last sentence, provided a [mcve] and continued from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications which clear only part of the screen generally (except for hard-coded applications using escape-sequences) use the low-level [terminfo](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html) or [termcap](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_termcap.3x.html) interfaces to the terminal database.  curses does have a special case (the [filter](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-filter_nofilter) function) which also is useful for this purpose.

The example shown in the screenshot uses hard-coded escapes (see [source code](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/src/ansi.go)), which could be improved, e.g., using one of the existing terminfo interfaces (such as [xo](https://github.com/xo/terminfo) or [tcell](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mau.fi/tcell/terminfo)).

All of those are aimed at very simple applications.  Reading their source code is the best way to understand how they work.